# Play 2.0 "management" console commands

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I'd like to create some custom commands to manage my play 2.0 application (similar to Django's management commands), so I can run things like `play import-data <data>`.

This seems to be something one would do by writing SBT commands (like Play's own), but specific to the particular project and with access to a project's resources (models etc.)

Being fairly new to Scala, and new to both Play and SBT, I cannot get my head around how to do this, and particularly the dependency management that is involved.  The [SBT plugin documentation](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Plugins) is very nice, but it seems to assume I want to create standalone, published plugins, rather than ones that depend on the main project.

Does anyone know of a walkthrough for something similar, or have any specific suggestions for how "management commands" could otherwise be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

To begin, you could take a look at the existing Play's sbt-plugins: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at the Play sbt-plugins but they're very much like the typical "publish to a repository and then link to in plugins.sbt" type thing. The commands I want to write only pertain to my project and depend on its specific code, so that seems like total overkill.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, but AFAIK sbt is mainly used as a build tool, not a cli for a running Play app.

Comment: Indeed, it looks that way. I have now discovered the sbt `run-main` command, which pretty much does what I want (albeit with some Play-specific trickiness to do with needing a running application for anything useful) and I think that'll suffice for the time being. I'll leave this question open for a little while though.

Comment: You could also simply use a Java class containing a `main()` method. But you'd hit the same issue (running app and so on).

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm doing with run-main more or less. I do hope to find some enlightenment here since I think having an easy way to write command-line interfaces to a webapp is incredibly useful.

Comment: @Mikesname Could you tell us what Play-specific trickiness you had to do in order to have a running application? I am more or less in the same business as you were. Thank you!

Comment: @Andrea: If I recall, I was referring to having to run stuff that used my models and app libs from within a FakeApplication. This required having the play-test dependencies available. As a shortcut I just bunged my commands in the test directory. Gist here: https://gist.github.com/4594442

Comment: Thank you very much! I usually do that trick in the console to be able to work with the application in the shell.